# Display or use content from <div> tags

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form, with a hidden input:

```
<input id="producten" type="hidden" name="producten" value="<div class='simpleCart_items'></div>"/>
```

I want to get the content that is in between the div's and use that content to submit with the form. That content is created when the page loads. What it does now, is it takes the actual code (`<div etc></div`).

Hope someone can help me with this! I am familiar with PHP and javascript.

Thanks

Comment: there's better ways of passing data around than inside divs inside a hidden form field...

Comment: Ouch. This is a really bad idea, the way you're currently doing it. There is no content "inbetween the divs" because there are no divs - it's just a string of HTML, not a parsed set of elements.

Comment: How could I 'extract' the content from those <div>'s, after the page has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formBeforeSubmit()
{
    document.getElementById('producten').value = document.getElementById('simpleCart_items').innerHTML;
    return true;
}
</script>

<div id="simpleCart_items">myContent</div>

<form action="..." method="POST" onsubmit="formBeforeSubmit();">
    <input id="producten" type="hidden" name="producten" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

But don't put the whole div in the value of the input field.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to strip out the element from the value, then that is hands down the best thing to do, i.e. (something like what web-nfo.com was suggested.

If not you can do this with pure JS:

```
var el = document.getElementById('producten').value;
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(el, "text/xml");
document.getElementById('producten').value = doc.firstChild.innerHTML;
```

or

If you have access to jQuery, you can do this:

```
var el = $('#producten').val();
var elVal = $(el).text();
$('#producten').val(elVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the contents between those `div`s in PHP

you can try this

```
$str =  "<div class='simpleCart_items'>hello world</div>";
$str = substr($str, 30);
$str = substr($str, 0, -6);

echo $str; // hello world
```